# How to get AM/PM in System Date and Time in MFC(VC++ )?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How to get  AM/PM in System date and time in this format (15-Nov-2010 16:24 PM) in MFC ?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`COleDateTime::Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bab3feb1(VS.80).aspx) with the correct format string.